# Valid KnowledgeBaseId and SubscriptionKey not provided

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I need help, after migrating to the new QNAMaker, im now getting an error: Valid KnowledgeBaseId and SubscriptionKey not provided. Use QnAMakerServiceAttribute or set fields on QnAMakerDialog. What am i missing? Subscription Key and KnowledgebaseID was already added. I simply followed the sample http request upong publishing in the qnamaker portal.

[image]

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using QnAMakerDialog;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker;

namespace TEST.Dialog
{
[Serializable]

[QnAMaker(authKey:"013ffd97-XXXX-XXXX-981f-ea298085591c", knowledgebaseId:"f81ce668-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-ad20c5f4d3fa", endpointHostName:"https://XXXX.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker")]
public class QnADialog : QnAMakerDialog<object>
{
   public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.PrivateConversationData.TryGetValue("Name", out name);
        await context.PostAsync($"Hello {name}. The QnA Dialog was started. Ask a question.");
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

    }

    public async Task DefaultMatchHandler(IDialogContext context, string originalQueryText, QnAMakerResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            // ProcessResultAndCreateMessageActivity will remove any attachment markup from the results answer
            // and add any attachments to a new message activity with the message activity text set by default
            // to the answer property from the result
           // var messageActivity = ProcessResultAndCreateMessageActivity(context, ref result);
            if (result.Score > 30 && result.Answer != NOMATCH)
            {
                await context.PostAsync(result.Answer);
                context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                await context.Forward(new RootLuisDialog(), DialogsCompleted, context.Activity, CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }

    public override async Task NoMatchHandler(IDialogContext context, string originalQueryText)
    {
        try
        {
            await context.Forward(new RootLuisDialog(), DialogsCompleted, context.Activity, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        // calculate something for us to return
        int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

        // return our reply to the user
        //await context.PostAsync($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");

        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
        return;
    }

     private async Task DialogsCompleted(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var success = await result;
        //if (!(bool)success)
        //    await context.PostAsync("I'm sorry. I didn't understand you.");

        //context.UserData.Clear();
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }


    [QnAMakerResponseHandler(30)]
    public async Task LowScoreHandler(IDialogContext context, string originalQueryText, QnAMakerResult result)
    {
        //await context.PostAsync($"I found an answer that might help: {result.Answer}");
        await context.Forward(new RootLuisDialog(), DialogsCompleted, context.Activity, CancellationToken.None);
        //context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }
}
}
```

**RootDialog that calls QNAMaker:**

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace Test.Dialog
{
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public string name = string.Empty;
    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }


     private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        try
       {
            //Some User Code that retreives user via PrivateConversationData




            //Calls QNADialog

            context.Call(new QnADialog(), MessageReceivedAsync);
       }
}
```

}

My Version of CognitiveServices: 
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.1.1.7 
Bot Builder,Bot Connector :3.15.2.2
QNADialog: 1.2.0

Comment: Which version of Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices package are you using? And can you add more details of your Dialog implementation?

Comment: already added and updated all the codes including the latest of everything, no luck still

Comment: I will try to have a look when I got some time. Can you also add the Dialog calling your QnADialog ?

Comment: done adding rootdialog, rootdialog is called on MessageController under  activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using [QnAMakerDialog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/QnAMakerDialog/) with QnA Maker service v4.0, but in description of NuGet package [QnAMakerDialog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/QnAMakerDialog/) and GitHub readme of [QnAMakerDialog (updated to work with QnA Maker v3 API)](https://github.com/garypretty/botframework/tree/master/QnAMakerDialog), we can find that this QnAMakerDialog nugget package can work with v3 of the QnA Maker API, not QnA Maker service v4.0.

To work with QnA Maker service v4.0, as Nicolas R said, you can use this NuGet package: ***[Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices)*** to create your QnAMakerDialog.

```
[Serializable]
public class QnADialog : QnAMakerDialog
{
    public QnADialog() : base(new QnAMakerService(new QnAMakerAttribute("{qnaAuthKey_here}", " {knowledgebaseId_here}", "No good match in FAQ.", 0.5, 1, "https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker")))
    { }

    //other code logic
}
```

Comment: Please uninstall the NuGet package [QnAMakerDialog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/QnAMakerDialog/) for your project.

Comment: what will i extend my class with ? public class QnADialog : QnAMakerDialog<object>

Comment: Hi @anonymous1110, I updated with code snippet of my QnADialog class.

Comment: i was finally able to connect, but my override methods like the nomatchhandler and defaultmatchhandler no longer works, any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

As explained on the Generally Available announcement, you can still use `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices` package in your code: the code has been changed to handle bot v1 to v3 calls and new v4 (GA version).

**You just have to add the necessary information, that is to say the endpoint hostname** as previously it was hosted on Microsoft side.

So your dialog code will look like the following (see Github official sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/QnAMaker/SimpleQnABot/Dialogs/SimpleQnADialog.cs#L8)):

```
[Serializable]
[QnAMaker("set yout authorization key here", "set your kbid here", <score threshold>, <number of results>, "endpoint hostname")]
public class SimpleQnADialog : QnAMakerDialog
{
}
```

Comment: my hostname would be the one under Host: https://XXXX/qnamaker correct?

Comment: i already addded those lines and i also used the Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices. My error now is : Valid KnowledgeBaseId and SubscriptionKey not provided. Use QnAMakerServiceAttribute or set fields on QnAMakerDialog

Comment: I can't help you more if you do not add all your Dialog and answer my question in comment about the version of the package you are using

Comment: im trying again from scratch, everytime im trying to install the Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.1.1.7 it causes a  package doest not contain a manifest error on my nugget package manager > Installed. my bot builder is at 3.12.2.4 do i really need to install the cognitiveservices?

Comment: "do i really need to install the cognitiveservices?": if you want to use QnAMakerDialog, yes, it's contained in this nuget package, not on main bot builder one